# How to implement halo effect with Wpf 3D?

Tags: wpf, 3d, lighting

I'm trying to build a 3D earth with Wpf Viewport3D. I have created the earth and it works pretty good. Then I want to add a halo effect around the earth like this attached image:

[image: Halo effect example].

Some recommend to use diffuse material for the globe model. Then build a slight larger globe model with emissive material and little opacity. But the effect is not very good. It affects the color of diffusion material like this:

[image: Unsatisfactory halo]

How can I implement the effect like the first screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly this by creating a ring, inner radius the same radius as the planet and an outer radius to relect the atmospheric depth. Oriented to 'face me'. Using texture coordinates into a LinearGradientBrush to have the atmosphere fade from sky blue to transparent black.

Alternatively, there are some fairly good PNGs around of semi-transparent cloud layers you could use on the slightly larger sphere.